# Can I uninstall sudo in ubuntu 14.04 using Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: grub2, sudo, recovery-mode

`sudo` command in my terminal gives error:

```
sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set
```

In the root shell prompt in recovery mode of grub, I am not able to type any command. I can only see `root@user:~#`. Any key press has no response.

So can I remove the sudo package and reinstall it? Will it effect any other files?

Answer (score 0):

Your second mentioned problem (can't type at root prompt in recovery mode) suggests there is much more wrong with your installation than being unable to use sudo.  I'd suggest it's probably the simplest way out to backup your personal data (you should be able to do that from a Live CD or USB) and reinstall Ubuntu to get a clean, working system.

Uninstalling sudo is almost certainly a bad idea; I haven't tried it, but it's central to the way Ubuntu is designed to work (you can't do *anything* in privileged mode without it, on a default installation).  It certainly won't fix the problem with recovery mode, and it's likely to uninstall so many dependent packages that you'll be forced into reinstalling anyway.

Comment: Your larger point that sudo is not the problem here is correct; but just for the record, sudo is easily uninstalled. Just be sure to set a password for root first. Sudo has only a few dependencies and all are used by lots of other packages, so none of them will be autoremoved. Debian, for example, does not install sudo by default if you set a root password during install. If you don't set a root password, it installs sudo and adds the main user to the sudo group. In other words, it then sets itself up like Ubuntu. Again, not recommending, just pointing out.